# Is the phrase "far away" needed here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Avatar The Way of Water* (2022), after he and his family witnessed the dead body of Mother Tulkun floating
in the sea, Tonowari gave a speech to his clan:

> Tonowari: This war has come to us. We knew about this hunting of our
> tulkun people. But it was over the horizon, **far away**.

Is the phrase "far away" needed here?

Comment: You might as well ask whether ***over the horizon*** is "needed". And if you *did* want to reduce the word-count, cutting that out would get rid of one more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the site.

Is it *needed*?  No. The sentence makes sense without that. It even means the same thing, pretty much.

But it does add something. It adds emphasis and specificity. Something could be over the horizon and not *that* far away. Technically, the horizon is only about 3 miles away (about 5 km). By adding "far away" he is saying that he means far away. Also, with both "over the horizon" and "far away" the sentence is a bit more expressive and even poetic.

Comment: A leader making a speech to their clan would probably wax poetic, especially if Hollywood screenwriters have anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

It's just emphasis.

It was over the horizon, far away… but now it is within sight, nearby.